# How to query many to many relationship?

Tags: jpa, jpql

So I got many to many relationship in two different entities. One has a list of the other and the other has a list of the first one. My question is how to make query that takes one field of the entity + the collection. For example Professors and Projects are related many to many, how to get the name of all  professors + the projects they are involved in? Please if you have ideas share deeply and broadly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use JP QL Projections, select on the Professor's name plus the properties of the Project entity associated with the professor. Using your example:

```
@Entity
public class Professor {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private Collection<Projects> projects;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Project {
  private Long id;
  private String status;
  private Collection<Professor> professors;
  ...
}
```

Sample data:
Your Professor table has 2 rows:
1 Mark
2 John

Your Project table has 4 rows:
1 A DELAYED
2 B COMPLETED
3 C ON-TRACK
4 D COMPLETED

The JOIN table (the first column is the Professor ID, 2nd column is the Project ID):
1 1
1 2
2 3
2 4

Your JPA Query will be like:

```
SELECT prof.name, proj.name, proj.status FROM Professor prof JOIN prof.projects proj
```

Then the results will be:
Mark A DELAYED
Mark B COMPLETED
John C ON-TRACK
John D COMPLETED

However, if you're trying use projection on the Professor name plus its project collections, that will not be possible in JP QL. JP QL only allows single-valued path expression in the SELECT clause.

Example: This is NOT A VALID JP QL Query, since prof.projects is a collection-valued path expression.

```
SELECT prof.name, prof.projects FROM Professor prof
```